How to inject IOption<T> into class using IWebHost builder's AddHttpClient() without UseStartup()
I am trying inject my IOptions into a class that requires a HttpClient and IOptions.
public class MyHttpService : IMyHttpService 
{
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   private readonly IOptions<MyOption> _myOption;

   MyHttpService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<MyOption> myOption)
   {
      _httpClient = httpClient;
      _myOption = myOption;
   } 

   //Further methods be here...
}

public class MyOption
{
   public string MyStringSetting {get;set;}
   //More settings be here...
}

Inside appsettings.json
{
   "MyOptions":{
     "MyStringSetting": "SomeSetting"
   }
}

Inside Program.cs
IWebHostBuilder builder = 
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.Configure()
.ConfigureLogging()
.UseNLog()
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
   services.AddOptions();
   IConfiguration configuration = context.Configuration;
   services.Configure<MyOption>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
   services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpService,MyHttpService>((provider,client) =>
   {
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(\*api url*\);
   });
})

IWebHost webHost = builder.build();
webHost.Run();

When investigating the MyHttpService, it was not injecting the the IOptions.
What am I missing?
I was expecting that the ConfigureServices() would resolve the IOptions dependency and inject the implemented MyOptions.

--edited for clarity--
The IOption<MyOption> dependency was actually injected.
The MyHttpService class which was using Options<MyOption> implementation which needed configuration and injection.
Inside of the MyHttpService class there was a method overload that ignored the Options<MyOption>.
public class MyHttpService : IMyHttpService 
{
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   private readonly IOptions<MyOption> _myOption;

   MyHttpService(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<**SomeOtherOption**> myOption)
   {
      _httpClient = httpClient;
      _myOption = myOption;
   } 

   ////Implemented Methods (that were overloaded!!!)
   public void Method(){/*does something with IOptions*/}
   public void Method(IOptions<T>){/*Method() overloaded with IOptions<T>*/}
}

public class MyOption
{
   public string MyStringSetting {get;set;}
   //More settings be here...
}

public class SomeOtherOption
{
   public string MyStringSetting {get;set;}
   //More settings be here...
}

Inside appsettings.json
{
   "MyOptions":{
     "MyStringSetting": "SomeSetting"
   },
   "SomeOtherOptions":{  //<--This was missing
     "MyStringSetting": "SomeSetting"
   }
}

Inside Program.cs
IWebHostBuilder builder = 
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.Configure()
.ConfigureLogging()
.UseNLog()
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
   services.AddOptions();
   IConfiguration configuration = context.Configuration;
   services.Configure<MyOption>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
   services.Configure<SomeOtherOption>(configuration.GetSection("SomeOtherOptions"));
   services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpService,MyHttpService>((provider,client) =>
   {
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(MyOption);
   });

   ///Other Services that required **IMyHttpService** but used **SomeOtherOption** instead!!!
})

IWebHost webHost = builder.build();
webHost.Run();

TLDR;
IOptions<T> DI was a red herring.
There was an overloaded method that ignored the DI, and disguised the actual problem.

Can you elaborate on how that class was the problem? I think others would benefit from that detail.

I just needed to dig through the code a bit deeper. Hopefully this red herring will help others to troubleshoot their code.
